# What are some good places to receive feedback?

Tags: feedback

A lot of people have been asking for some feedback about their poem/story. In an attempt to help find them a website, I couldn't. I googled `feedback for writing` however I didn't find any websites where you can post your writing and receive feedback.

I'm not sure if this is considered on-topic, but might as well ask: What are some websites or places where you can receive feedback for your writing?

Comment: Heya! We've had some very similar questions before; I hope this'll help :D https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/where-is-a-good-place-to-find-beta-readers

Comment: @Standback Ah yes. I believe my question is a duplicate. I never knew they were called beta-readers.

Comment: No worries :D Duplicates are handy to point lots of different phrasings at the same base question :)

Comment: Bonus terminology: if you exchange feedback duties with another writer (which I recommend), they're called critique partners.